# C# seperate WebRequest CSV columns into array

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I want to create an array that contains the prices of given stocks.

`iStockTableRows` is the amount of stocks, for example "3".

`sSymbols` contains the stock names "AAPL+GOOG+MSFT".

`"http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + sSymbols + "&f=a"` are the prices of the stocks separated into multiple lines.

```
WebRequest wrPrice = WebRequest.Create("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + sSymbols + "&f=a"); //sSymbols zb. "AAPL+GOOG+MSFT"
WebResponse wResp = wrPrice.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
double[] dCurrentPrice = new double[iStockTableRows];
int iLine = 0;

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
        dCurrentPrice[iLine] = double.Parse(sr.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        iLine++;
}

sr.Close();
```

`ReadLine()` doesn't return anything for some reason and I get  `System.FormatException` at

```
dCurrentPrice[iLine] = double.Parse(sr.ReadLine(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

because of that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot actually say why your approach is not working. 
I have tried sending a request but received string of length 5 with response Content-Length: 7. It looks like there is a BOM or something like this which creates some problems for line-by-line reading from a stream.

I would do this in any of these two ways.

1. StreamReader ReadToEnd()

   ```
   string csvContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
   ```

And then parse this. It looks more safe and convenient.
It looks like there is no necessity in reading the response line by line.

2. Or use TryParse if you are sure that the response is N float numbers.
   This worked for me:

   ```
   string[] names = new [] {"AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"};

   string url = String.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}&f=a", String.Join(",", names));
   WebRequest wrPrice = WebRequest.Create(url);
   WebResponse wResp = wrPrice.GetResponse();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
   double[] dCurrentPrice = new double[names.Length];

   int iLine = 0;
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
       double val;
       if (double.TryParse(sr.ReadLine(), 
                           System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           out val))
       {
           dCurrentPrice[iLine++] = val;
       }
   }
   sr.Close();

   Array.ForEach(dCurrentPrice, x => Console.WriteLine(x));

   return;
   ```